# Regular expression with separator and optional part

Tags: objective-c, regex, option-type

I seem to have a mental block when it comes to regular expressions, so I hope you can help me.

I have a string that has this format

```
.* :: .* :: .*
```

But sometimes like this:

```
.* :: .*
```

I want to capture the first 2 groups of characters, like this

```
(.*) :: (.*) :: .*
```

But I don't know how to modify my expression so that the last :: and characters are optional. I've tried using parenthesis and `?`, but I just can't get it to work as desired.

Thanks

Comment: Check my revised answer below. I got it working and tested it fully. Unlike the other answers here, it also allows single : in your strings with no problem, looking only for double ::.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
(.*?) :: (.*?(?= :: |$))
```

Here's a breakdown of how it works:

-> This isolates the first batch of characters before the first :: and saves it to group $1.

```
(.*?)
```

-> Next, this chunk does two things. First, it uses .*? to get the second batch of characters. After this, the zero-width positive look-ahead assertion (?= :: |$) requires that the characters end with another :: or $, the end of the text, but does not include them in the match group, meaning that only the second batch of characters are saved to $2.

```
(.*?(?= :: |$))
```

I tested in Objective-C against these string with success:

- "ABC :: DEF"
- "ABC :: DEF :: GHI"
- "A:B:C :: D:E:F" (this lets single : be in the texts between ::)
- "A:B:C :: D:E:F :: G:H:I" (this lets single : be in the texts between ::)

Comment: That's what @Petar Ivanov had originally suggested, but you can see by my first comment that it didn't quite work.

Comment: I was able to find a RegEx that matched exactly as you requested when testing in Objective-C, please see my revised answer.

Comment: Yes, this totally did it. You are a genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
([^:]*) :: ([^:]*) (:: ([^:]*))?
```

The captured groups you access then are 1, 2 and 4 (where 4 might be empty).

EDIT:

The `.*?` is non-greedy  `.*`, i.e. it matches as few wild card characters as possible.
This would prevent the first group to match the first two patterns.

Another option would be to replace `.*` with `[^:]*` if you know that the pattern doesn't contain `:`.

Comment: Close, but the first and second groups are bunched up into one. 1 is `.* :: .*` and 2 is the last `.*`. It only works well when the last pattern is missing.

Comment: The problem is that the text does have : in it.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
(.* ::){2}(?:::)?
```

Match two things followed by `::`, and the last can have an optional `::`.

Comment: Also close, but it only works when I have the 3 groups of characters and the 2 separators. It appends the `::` at the end of my strings, too.